# Snapshot gerado pelo Selenium está com dimensões muito grande

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Boa tarde pessoal.

Eu estou utilizando o FirefoxDriver na versão 2.53.0 e ao tirar snapshot de um site está sendo gerado uma imagem com dimensões muito grande (111159x17555).

Alguém sabe uma forma de corrigir esse problema?

Já tentei definir a dimensão do navegador com o seguinte código:

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1366, 768));
```

E o problema persistiu.

Segue o exemplo de um snapshot que foi gerado.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código utilizado para tirar o snapshot:

```
public static void saveScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String path) {
    File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    try {
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(path));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Você poderia postar o código que está usando para tirar o *screenshoot*? (e.g., todo o bloco até a parte em que você chama `getScreenshotAs`).

Comment: Acrescentei o código no post.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se resolve seu caso, mais poderia tentar com base no meu código que utilizo em outro sistema. Realmente não sei se soluciona seu problema, mais vale a dica.

```
public BufferedImage screenshot(WebDriver driver) throws IOException {
    File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    BufferedImage fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
    return fullImg;
}
```

E chamo um método para persistir

```
public boolean persistScreenshot(BufferedImage image, String location) {
    try {
        File file = new File(location);
        if (file.exists()) {
            file.delete();
        }
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

A questão é que o meu eu transformo em um BufferedImage pois nem sempre necessito da persistência direta do mesmo.
Vla etalvez testar se isto não solucionaria o problema de ele se redimencionar de forma errada.

Comment: Kelvin obrigado pela ajuda, mas o problema continua. Acredito que o problema não seja o código e sim o layout do site, porque se eu tirar snapshot de outro site a imagem sai perfeita.